# C++ pwrite() offset

Tags: c++

I’m looking to put together a C++ program to write some patterns to a disk device, but I’m running into an issue when I try to set an offset greater than 0. See example and code below.

Can anyone tell me what I’m doing wrong?

Thanks,

```
root@solaris:~/# CC simple_test.cc
root@solaris:~/# ./a.out
Insert device name, for example: /dev/rdsk/c2t600A0B800011238000001D3D45DA78A7d0s1
/dev/rdsk/c0t6000402E5000000035969F0C97324D24d0s2
iteration: 0. offset: 0
offset: 1048577
iteration: 1. offset: 1048577
WRITE operation error: 22; offset: 1048577
offset: 2097154
iteration: 2. offset: 2097154
WRITE operation error: 22; offset: 2097154
offset: 3145731
iteration: 3. offset: 3145731
WRITE operation error: 22; offset: 3145731
offset: 4194308
iteration: 4. offset: 4194308
WRITE operation error: 22; offset: 4194308
offset: 5242885
Test completed
root@solaris:~/# cat simple_test.cc
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sstream>

#define BS           1048576
using namespace std;
const char PATTERN[ ] = { 'A' };

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char dev[ 100 ];
    printf( "Insert device name, for example: /dev/rdsk/c2t600A0B800011238000001D3D45DA78A7d0s1\n" );
    scanf( "%s", dev );
    int fd;
    if ( ( fd = open( dev, O_RDWR ) ) == -1 )
    {
        printf( "error opening device: %s\n", dev );
        return 1;
    }

    char* pattern = new char[ BS ];
    memset ( pattern, PATTERN[0], BS );
    int offset = 0;
    int nbytes = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++ ) {
        cout << "iteration: " << i << ". offset: " << offset << endl;
        nbytes = pwrite( fd, pattern, BS, offset );
        if ( nbytes != BS )
            printf( "WRITE operation error: %d; offset: %ld\n", errno, offset );
        offset += BS + 1;
        cout << "offset: " << offset << endl;
    }

    delete pattern;
    printf( "Test completed\n" );
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not certain, but aren't you required to write to block devices in blocks? So your offset has to be a multiple of the block size. But you increment it by BS + 1. Why the +1? I think if you stick with += BS it might work.

Comment: Thanks! I thought I had tried that in the past without success, but it's certainly working now. It seems the offset is specified in bytes and I need to be aligned to 512, which makes sense as the sector size of the block device.